# Create two image on a line with hover text in Blgger

Tags: image, hover, blogger, caption

I'm trying to create a page of images for my blog using **blogger.com**. The key is that I want to be able to have text appear over a photo when it is hovered over. I figured out how to do this by using the code in [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/blogger/MbzfUSlb9p0). (I wasn't able to put it in this post with proper formatting)

However, I'm not very good at html and what I'd really like to do is have **TWO PHOTOS on the same line** with this effect. Does anyone know how to make this happen? If not, does anyone know how to at least center the image on the page.

(If this isn't possible, how can I get two images on the same line with captions. I can get two images on the same line but when I add a caption it forces the second picture to a new line.)

If you have a ***simpler way to add the hover effect*** to an image, please let me know, as I ideally would not like to have this much code for each image as I plan to have many images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will certainly bring 2 images next to each other. Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sangram27/5JywF/). It has hover as well as captions you needed with images.

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<div class="imgWrap">
  <img src="sample1.jpg" />
  <p class="imgDescription">First Image text.</p>
  <span style="font-size: small;">Caption text 1</span>
</div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="imgWrap">
  <img src="sample2.jpg" />
  <p class="imgDescription">Second image text</p>
  <span style="font-size: small;">Caption text 2</span>
</div></td>
</tr>
    </table>
```